# CSS sprite animation timing issues

Tags: css, css-animations, css-sprites

I can't seem to get the animation timing right on this

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYMgqE

```
.spinner {
          width: 36px;
          height: 36px;
          background: url('http://i.imgur.com/CYiaWsF.png') top center;
          animation: play 1s steps(10) infinite;
        }

        @keyframes play {
           100% { background-position: 0px -2844px; }
        }
```

I have tried numerous combinations, but it always comes out looking like a film reel.

Am I doing something wrong? Did I misunderstand CSS sprite animations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your math is off..I think.

The image is, apparently, 2844 px tall...so the number of steps should be the height divided by the element height

2844 / 36 = 79

```css
.spinner {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/CYiaWsF.png') top center;
  -webkit-animation: play 1s steps(79) infinite;
  animation: play 1s steps(79) infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes play {
  100% {
    background-position: 0px -2844px;
  }
}
@keyframes play {
  100% {
    background-position: 0px -2844px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner"></div>
```

Comment: That's amazing! None of the tutorials said this. I'm in awe it was such a simple solution that I've completely overlooked.